# how to find no. of similar characters in two strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I need to find the no. of similar characters between two strings using JS/PHP

Example
str1: Mack 
str2: Michelle

Similar Characters: "M" "C"
similar character count: 2

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: I tried in PHP, similar_text() 
But it aint accurate.

Comment: You need to try harder, if nothing built-in works, then try to build your own thing, then come back with the code that failed, post an example to reproduce the problem and explain what you tried to solve it.

Comment: found the way to do it, thanks to @Scalpweb :)

Comment: Great :) Please note my answer as accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your precision, here is my solution:

```
str1 = str1.toUpperCase();
str2 = str2.toUpperCase();
var counter = 0, find = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++)
{
    find = str2.indexOf(str1.charAt(i));
    if(find > -1)
    {
      counter++;
      str2 = str2.substr(0, find) + str2.substr(find + 1);
    }
}
alert("Result: "+counter);
```

It works with the 2 examples you gave us:

Michellle and Michelle = 8
Sneha and naveen = 3

Answer (score 1):

I'll do this:

```
str1 = str1.toUpperCase();
str2 = str2.toUpperCase();
var counter = 0;
var min = Math.min(str1.length, str2.length);
for(var i = 0; i < min; i++)
{
   if(str1.charAt(i) === star2.charAt(i))
      counter++;
}
alert("Result: "+counter);
```

Comment: Use toLowerCase if you want to detect the "C".

Comment: Was editing it when you posted your message. I used toUpperCase :)

Comment: That won't be correct.. looping only to the end of the shorter string will ignore characters that are actually important. (Ie. "zzzy" "yyy" would not find that "y" is in both strings.)

Comment: Actually my previous comment is assuming that the matching characters don't have to have the same index.

Comment: It depends on what he really wants. On his exemple, he showns two caracters on the exact same positions (1st and 3rd), so I thought he wants to count only them. If he says that he want to test for every caracters but not look at the positions, I will provide another script. (as you just said while i was typing this)

Comment: Ah yeah, fair enough.

Comment: I am trying to build a simple flames game.
Where you need to find the similar character between names.
Jason and Jane

The letters 'J', 'A' and 'N' are the same between two names.

But there seems to be an issue with this solution

Lets say I add, Michellle and Michelle: character count should be 8
But it shows 7

Comment: Ok, I posted a new answer that will covr your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function

```
<?php
    echo "character count: ". similar_text("Mack","Michelle");
?>
```

**Output**

```
character count: 2
```

Comment: Its not effective, sometimes they don't give you the exact count.

Comment: if you try Sneha and naveen. 

echo "character count: ". similar_text("sneha","naveen");

It should echo: 3
But it echo's 2

Answer (score 0):

I'd need more examples to make sure this works, but using regular expressions might work for you:

```
function similar_text_regex(str1, str2){
    var regEx = new RegExp('['+str2+']', 'gi');
    var matchCnt = str1.match(regEx2).length;
    return matchCnt;
}

console.log(similar_text_regex('Michelle', 'Michellle')); // --> 8
console.log(similar_text_regex('Jason', 'Jane')); // --> 3
console.log(similar_text_regex("sneha","naveen")); // --> 3
```

Comment: He said that for Michellle and Michelle it should returns 8.

Comment: Should be fixed now then.. I just figured, that if matching left to right AND right to left would give the best results..